# So close to fixing touchpad issues: How to edit Tablet mode actions?

Tags: gnome, touchpad, touchscreen, tablet

As more and more people today, I have a 2 in 1 laptop. A laptop with touchscreen and a rotatable display. Mine is from Lenovo and is from the ideapad flex series. Nice little device!

It has one problem however. When going into 'tablet mode', the keyboard and touchpad disable themselves. That's all great and working fine. However, when I revert back into regular mode only the keyboard toggles itself on. The icon for the touchpad activation appears, but does nothing.

I have found a command that relies on xdotool to work, but does reliably toggle the touchpad. I added it to my gnome top bar using the Guillotine shell extension. This is however not the most elegant solution. **The best way to fix this is to add this command to the list of commands that executes when the sensors are triggered. I just don't know where to look and have not found an answer yet. Does anyone here know where I can find this?**

For anyone with the same problem as me and wants a quick and dirty fix right now: try installing xdotool

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Find the name of the instance that toggles your touchpad

```
xmodmap -pke | grep TouchpadToggle
```

For me it was XF86TouchpadToggle. With xdotool you can run this instance with a command

```
xdotool key XF86TouchpadToggle
```

I used Guillotine to add this to my top bar: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3981/guillotine/

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to find a solution.

If you run **libinput debug-events** in your terminal, you will see that every time you switch your convertible device into tablet mode, GNOME sends a KEY_21 keypress, which is  the same thing as XF86TouchpadToggle. With this taken into account, you can open GNOME dconf Editor and navigate to **/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/**. Here, you can unbind the function that disables the touchpad by changing its value to **['']**. Alternatively, you can bind it to a different key if you want to keep the ability to disable the touchpad on command.

In my case, making the aforementioned changes stopped GNOME from disabling my convertible laptop's touchpad without reenabling it later. Now it's handled just by the hardware itself and it works reliably: the touchpad is disabled in tablet configuration and it comes right back in normal configuration.